# Reactjs creating a array containing a bunch of objects using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a array which contains a bunch of objects like this and insert them upon different actions:

```
[
{price: 'price_1M73OzIRkO5W1JretwretkAHa', quantity: 1},
{price: 'price_1M73OzI4545W1JretwretkAHa', quantity: 3},
{price: 'price_1M73OzIRkO4545twr45kAHa', quantity:2}
]
```

However I cant seem to add in a third object it just overwrittes the second one.

```
const [allPlans, setAllPlans] = useState([]);

setAllPlans([{...allPlans, price:'price_1M73OzIRkO5W1JretwretkAHa', quantity: 1}]);
```

Thank you for the help!

update:
Early in the code I do do this to update the quanity on the orginal entry. Could this be creating the issue?

```
setAllPlans({...allPlans,"quantity": userAmount});
```

Update: Here is a link to a working example of the problem corrected:
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-ully-594ihs?file=/src/App.js:280-287

Comment: You want to spread out the array of existing objects, and add a new object to that array: `setAllPlans([ ...allPlans, newObj ]);`

Comment: Is `allPlans` initially set to that array you mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
setAllPlans(allplans => [...allplans, {price:'price_1M73OzIRkO5W1JretwretkAHa', quantity: 1}]);
```

Here's an additional link demonstrating how this works: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-ooi7og?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: You really need to test the code before you post it. This won't work.

Comment: edited, why wont it work?

Comment: Well, it will work now. But your previous edit would not work.

Comment: Please add an explanation of *why* this works but the OPs code doesn't. Teach a man to fish and whatnot.

Comment: That actually gives me this error: allplans is not iterable

Comment: @Robert Can you post what you're trying and the output

Comment: I'm doing this like you said: setAllPlans(allplans => [...allplans, {price: 'price_1M73PYIRkO5W1JjE3tI4pVZI', quantity: 1}]);

The output is simply: signup.js:566 Uncaught TypeError: allplans is not iterable

Comment: It's important for us to know the types and everything, can you post more code to the original question?

Comment: @Sean I've updated the post to add the type

Comment: Somemthing is wrong in your code, here's a link to show how this works: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-ooi7og?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: I updated my code as I do adjust the quanity on the orginal entry before adding the additional lines. Could that be creating the issue?

Comment: Yes that's incorrect. In that example you are trying to spread the array within an object

Comment: ok so I am adjusting the quanity incorrectly? What would be the proper way to adjust that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249839/discussion-between-sean-and-robert).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a cleaner way to do it, but you can try to do it with `push` method where `prevPlans` is going to be your initial array and you can add specific objects into that array.

```
setAllPlans((prevPlans) => [
      prevPlans.push({
        price: "i'm new here",
        quantity: 1
      })
    ]);
```

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [allPlans, setAllPlans] = useState([{
      price: "price_1M73OzIRkO5W1JretwretkAHa",
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      price: "price_1M73OzI4545W1JretwretkAHa",
      quantity: 3
    },
    {
      price: "price_1M73OzIRkO4545twr45kAHa",
      quantity: 2
    }
  ]);

  const addtoArray = () => {
    //prevPlans is your actual array and you push new object inside it and set your state
    setAllPlans((prevPlans) => [
      prevPlans.push({
        price: "i'm new here",
        quantity: 1
      })
    ]);
    console.log(allPlans);
  };

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    button onClick = {
      () => addtoArray()
    } > Click me < /button> <
    /div>
  );

}


// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <
  App / >
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```